# Database handling IOS Swift2.0

Tags: ios, database, swift2

I am new to IOS development. I wanted to create an application wherein I have two text boxes in which I want to insert two values (one each) and save. Two values should be saved in some database (local as well as on web server). Later I should be able to search this pair of two values by giving the first value.
(May be I can have local copy of database on phone itself but should be able to periodically upload/fetch the values from web server)

Is it possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite or CoreData for local storage. You can build a rest api on a server and store the data in the database of your choice. You could also use CloudKit instead of building a rest server solution.

Comment: Can I use CloudKit for multiple users? say there are multiple users, and each user can insert into two text boxes and save the values. (each user has separate set of two values)

Comment: Yes, Cloudkit supports a database for all users or for inidividual users.